# Change Text if checked - checkbox

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, checkbox, coffeescript

I have a checkbox with a explanatory Text:

```
<%= f.label :is_company do %>
  <%= f.check_box :is_company %>&nbsp;&nbsp; <span>Are you Representing a Company / Organization ?</span>
<% end %>
```

I need to change the text (if checkbox is triggered) from `Are you Representing a Company / Organization ?` to `I'm representing a Company / Organization !`

Can anyone help me out ?

HTML Output :

```
<label for="user_is_company">
  <input name="user[is_company]" type="hidden" value="0">
  <input id="user_is_company" name="user[is_company]" type="checkbox" value="1">&nbsp;&nbsp; 
  <span>Are you Representing a Company / Organization ?</span>
</label>
```

I work in **coffeescript**

So i made this abomination:

```
$(document).on "ready page:load", ->
  check = ->
    if input.checked
      document.getElementById("label_cmp").innerHTML = "I am representing a Company / Organization !"
    else
      document.getElementById("label_cmp").innerHTML = "Are you representing a Company / Organization ?"
  input = document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]")
  input.onchange = check
  check()
```

but i think its a lot of code, for nothing...

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Use Javascript. Toggle the text between `span` with the checkbox status.

Comment: I'm fairly new to coffee so i used a lot of code found on tutorials or snippets. But it seem's i cant get it working.

Comment: Could you show your html output from the above erb?

Comment: @DamienRoche Could you write the code as an Answer so i can look at it?

Comment: I can give you something once I have the html output from the erb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this *should* work. If it doesn't, have a play and tweak, then come back if you still have trouble.

```
$(document).on "ready page:load", ->
  $("input#user_is_company").on 'change', ->
    if $(this).is(":checked")
      $("#label_cmp").text("I'm representing a Company / Organization !")
    else
      $("#label_cmp").text("Are you Representing a Company / Organization ?")
```

Note: there is possibly an even shorter way to do this with jQuery `toggle`, but I have limited knowledge of JS.

Comment: Feel free to send over any errors. I doubt it will simply work copy/paste. Will likely need to amend a few things.

Comment: Would you mind joining me in Chat ? -> http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46562/coffe-toggle

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ->
  $("#user_is_company").on 'change', ->
      $("#label_cmp").text if $(this).is(":checked") then "I am representing a Company / Organization !" else "Are you representing a Company / Organization ?"
```

Compiles to...

```
$(function() {
  return $("#user_is_company").on('change', function() {
    return $("#label_cmp").text($(this).is(":checked") ? "I am representing a Company / Organization !" : "Are you representing a Company / Organization ?");
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VcFCL/

Some comments on my code choices...

```
# jquery shorthand form for on-ready wrapper function
# ensures DOM is loaded before executing inner function
$ ->
  # identify elements by ID alone, as ID should be unique on the page
  # listen for `change` event on selected element, and run callback
  $("#user_is_company").on 'change', ->
    # set the text of the label conditionally by the `checked` status of the selected element
    $("#label_cmp").text if $(this).is(":checked") then "I am representing a Company / Organization !" else "Are you representing a Company / Organization ?"
```